# Question about Variables in powershell script

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a script and I was wondering if there is a way to give a variable for example $a from a script firstscript.ps1 to an other script secondscript.ps1 executed by firstscript.ps1

To clarify what I'm saying :

I exec firstscript.ps1 it does different thing then it launch secondscript.ps1 on a remote computer and i would like the $a from to transfert firstscript.ps1 to secondscript.ps1

NB:I use psexec to exec the secondscript.ps1 remotely to a list of computer with admin right

I could write it in the second one but I want to avoid modification at the bare minimum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> then it launch secondscript.ps1 on a remote computer and i would like the $a from to transfert firstscript.ps1 to secondscript.ps1

Assuming you invoke the script remotely using `Invoke-Command`, pass arguments to the script via the `-ArgumentList` parameter:

```
## script1.ps1

# assign value to `$a`
$a = $(...)

# ...

# invoke script2.ps1 on remote machine with $a passed as first argument
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $nameOfRemoteComputer -FilePath path\to\script2.ps1 -ArgumentList $a
```

Then in `script2.ps1`, either read the argument value from `$args[0]`:

```
## script2.ps1

$a = $args[0] # grab argument value passed by script1.ps1

# work with $a here ...
```

... or declare a `param()` block with a parameter that the argument can be bound to:

```
## script2.ps1
param(
    $a # Let the runtime bind the argument value passed by script1.ps1 to this parameter variable
)

# work with $a here ...
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer , i use psexec to do it remotely for some reason does it still work ?

Comment: @Deer Please [add all relevant details to your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72227309/edit), I can't read your mind :)

Comment: R. Jenssen yeah sorry I added the last information

Comment: @Deer and how are you invoking powershell via psexec? `psexec \\remote -c "powershell.exe" -File script2.ps1` or something like that?

Comment: @R. Jenssen  depending where I deploy my script i use either  psexec \\remote -u domain\admin -p pwd  -c script2.ps1 or psexec \\remote -u  domain\admin -p pwd /c script2.ps1

Comment: @Deer Just add the argument after the command: `psexec \\remote [options] -c command $a`

Comment: @R. Jessen thanks a lot sir I will now work around this